# Hibernate can't find my hibernate.cfg.xml file

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

Pretty stupid/simple question. Doing an assignment and hibernate can't find my hibernate.cfg.xml file. I'm using IntelliJ and it is located inside my src folder. See my code below.

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee tempEmployee = new Employee("Ronald", "Customer Service", true);
        EmployeeDAO employeeDAO = new EmployeeDAO();
        employeeDAO.saveEmployee(tempEmployee);

    }
}
```

DAO:

```
public class EmployeeDAO {

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
            .configure()
            .addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class)
            .buildSessionFactory();


    public void saveEmployee(Employee employee){
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        try {

            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(employee);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "department")
    private String department;

    @Column(name = "working")
    private boolean working;

    public Employee(){}

    public Employee(String name, String department, boolean working) {
        this.name = name;
        this.department = department;
        this.working = working;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", department='" + department + '\'' +
                ", working=" + working +
                '}';
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public boolean isWorking() {
        return working;
    }

    public void setWorking(boolean working) {
        this.working = working;
    }
}
```

Hibernate config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee</property>
        <property name="connection.username">employee</property>
        <property name="connection.password">employee</property>
        <property name="dialect">com.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `configuration.configure("classpath:com/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");` this will locate your hibernate cfg.xml file also 
[read this tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/2924/hibernate-one-to-many-mapping-annotation)

Comment: where you have put your `cgf.xml` file ? mention the path

Comment: in IntelliJ, I have it in Appname/src

Comment: use `classpath:com/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml`

Comment: tried both of those. Even moved the file into my resource file. It's the weirdest thing.

Comment: did you try above mention path ?

Answer (score 0):

Mark your resources folder as resources from INTELLIJ IDEA.
Go to: File->Project Structure to do it.

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put your XML configuration file `hibernate.cfg.xml` under `src/main/resources`.

Also you can add it manually using **File → Project Structure → Add → Hibernate**:

[image]

And then add a descriptor in the same window as:

[image]

specify the path to your descriptor and press **OK**.